# localStorage("clicked", "")but when you click a button, set it to to ("clicked", "yes")and this cannot be reversed until you quit (close) the page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to set `localStorage` to `("clicked", "")` at all times, but when a button is clicked, change it to `("clicked", "yes")` and this shouldn't be undone unless you leave the page and enter it again. Are there any ways to do this?

```
localStorage.setItem("clicked", "");

(function checkFunction(){
  if (localStorage.getItem("clicked") === "yes") {
    localStorage.setItem("discountCode", "iloveventurebox0943");
    document.getElementById("discount-code-input").value = localStorage.getItem("discountCode");
    var discountPercentageStringFilter = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("Percentage"));
    discountPercentage.innerHTML = ("(20%)");
    var discountPercentageLS = localStorage.setItem("Percentage", "(20%)");
    var Subtotal = localStorage.getItem("Enterprise");
    toFixedFetch = (Subtotal * discountPercentageStringFilter);
    discountPricePrice.innerHTML = toFixedFetch.toFixed(2);
    var discountPricePriceLS = localStorage.setItem("Enterprise", toFixedFetch.toFixed(2));
    document.getElementById("discount-trigger").setAttribute("disabled", "");
    document.getElementById("discount-trigger").classList.add("disabled");
  }
  let discountTriggerBtn = document.getElementById("discount-trigger");
  discountTriggerBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let targetVar = document.getElementById("discount-code-input");
  (function checkDiscount() {
      var valueFiller = targetVar.value;
      let discountCode = "iloveventurebox0943";
      if (valueFiller === discountCode) {
        var discountPercentageStringFilter = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("Percentage"));
        discountPercentage.innerHTML = ("(20%)");
        var discountPercentageLS = localStorage.setItem("Percentage", "(20%)");
        var Subtotal = localStorage.getItem("Enterprise");
        toFixedFetch = (Subtotal * discountPercentageStringFilter);
        discountPricePrice.innerHTML = toFixedFetch.toFixed(2);
        var discountPricePriceLS = localStorage.setItem("Enterprise", toFixedFetch.toFixed(2));
        document.getElementById("discount-trigger").setAttribute("disabled", "");
        document.getElementById("discount-trigger").classList.add("disabled");

        localStorage.setItem("clicked", "yes");

        var Total = document.getElementById("total");
        Total.innerHTML = (Subtotal - discountPricePrice);
      }
    }
  )();
})
}())
```

I thought I could loop over and over but I just ended up going in hopeless circles :((

Comment: Would you consider a refresh of the page leaving? Or do you mean closing the browser window completely? Or do you mean navigating to another page?

Comment: You might be searching for [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage): it exists to address exactly this kind of scneario.